# Искажение картинок с помощью Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pillow, pil

Как можно сделать **content aware scale** (сжимает и разжимает фотографию с учетом содержимого) в питоне, которая будет искажать первую картинку и получать вторую на выходе?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел [сайт](https://shhnowisnottheti.me/content-aware-scaling/), который может делать подобное.

Comment: Ну дайте хотя бы заготовку - как вы читаете изображение. Там по идее ничего сложного, нужно только немного подумать.

Comment: Заготовки нет, но я нашел на гитхабе проект: https://github.com/dharness/seam_carving, который изменяет размер и деформирует картинку. Но только мне нужно, чтобы была только деформация.

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот вам примерно ваш кот, хотя я его исказил только по горизонтали, а нужно ещё видимо по вертикали, но тут я вам даю пример как с этим работать, дальше вы сами думайте. Код я запускал в Google Colab.

```
import numpy as np
import PIL
import requests

im=PIL.Image.open(requests.get('https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5QiV.jpg', stream=True).raw)
a = np.asarray(im)
b = np.zeros_like(a)
xs = a.shape[1] // 3
for x in range(xs//2):
    b[:,x] = a[:,x * 2]
for x in range(xs*2):
    b[:,xs//2 + x] = a[:,xs + x//2]
for x in range(xs//2):
    b[:,xs//2+xs*2 + x] = a[:,xs * 2 + x * 2]
imb = PIL.Image.fromarray(b)
imb
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если взять другие картинки, то будет заметная разница. То, что получилось с вашим кодом: https://ibb.co/3Y0k82w, и то, что получилось с ботом: https://ibb.co/sQ0GJ5P

Comment: Было бы круто найти и сопоставить ключевые точки на первом и втором изображении и получить карту искажений as is. :-)